# Filter query with order by and limit when using left join

Tags: mysql, sql, select

How to filter query with `order by` and `limit` when using left join

```
store_profile
id + store_name
1  | Accessorize.me 
2  | Active IT 
3  | Edushop
4  | Gift2Kids
5  | Heavyarm 
6  | Bamboo 

store_fee
id + store_id + date_end
1  |    1     | 27-6-2013
2  |    2     | 29-8-2013
3  |    3     | 02-6-2013
4  |    4     | 20-4-2013
5  |    4     | 01-7-2013
6  |    4     | 28-9-2013
7  |    5     | 03-9-2013
8  |    6     | 01-9-2013
```

my previous query

```
$order_by_for_sort_column = "order by $column" //sorting column

$query = "SELECT * FROM store_profile sp LEFT JOIN store_fee sf ON (sf.store_id = sp.id) $order_by_for_sort_column";
```

what i want is `order by id desc` and `limit 1` for table `store_fee` not for for entire query. So i can grab the latest date in `date_end` for each store.

As you can see for store_id 4(store_fee) i have 3 different date and i just want grab the latest date.

and the result should be something like this

```
1  | Accessorize.me  27-6-2013
2  | Active IT       29-8-2013
3  | Edushop         02-6-2013
4  | Gift2Kids       28-9-2013
5  | Heavyarm        03-9-2013
6  | Bamboo          01-9-2013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.id, a.store_name, MAX(b.date_End) date_end
FROM    store_profile a
        LEFT JOIN store_fee b
            ON a.ID = b.store_ID
GROUP   BY a.id, a.store_name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f662/8)

but if the datatype  `date_End` column is varchar, the above query won't work because it sorts the value by character and that it can mistakenly gives undesired result. `18-1-2013` is greater than `01-6-2013`.

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: You assume that `store_profile.store_name` is unique and use it as a key.  This may be wrong assumption and using business fields as keys, even when they are unique, is bad practice anyway.

Comment: @JW. What if `store_profile` will have more fields?  Am I right that all the fields will need to be listed twice: after `SELECT` and then again after `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov well you are thinking beyond the question but could still be a possibility. This answer is directly based on the example record above and and I was thinking of the performance. You are correct, you need to list all the fields listed on the `SELECT` clause and add those *non-aggregated* columns on the `GROUP BY` clause. `:)`

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov yes store_profile have more fields i just post the simple column so i can i understand how it's work, and JW thanks for your answer .. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM store_profile AS sp 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT store_id, MAX(date_end) 
    FROM store_fee 
    GROUP BY store_id
  ) AS sf 
    ON sp.id=sf.store_id;
```